# import/export modules from packages like tippyjs in browsers using only JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Is it possible to import, using only JavaScript ES6, modules from package like tippyjs (https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs)?
I tried to locally install the package via npm and use the files like this:

```
import tippy from '../node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy.esm.js';
```

but the browser give me this error:

```
validation.ts:46 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I have also tried, unsuccessfully, to "replicate" what the CDN is doing.
Thanks to what magic does the CDN work?

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
```

I know I am supposed to use CDNs, CDNs are great ecc., but I just want to have a single js module file in my HTML where all the import of my local files are:

```
<script type="module" src="js/modules.js"></script>
```

Can't rely only on CDNs.

What I am missing?

Please note that I'm not usign node.js, is just an html page and some JavaScript.

Comment: `import tippy from 'tippy.js';` doesn't work?

Comment: Sadly, no. This is the error i get:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "tippy.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"`

Comment: You have to load the module in your HTML with something like: `<script type="module" src="../node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy.esm.js"></script>` and your web server has to serve this file at this location. Don't forget that client side JavaScript is interpreted on the browser on the client computer and the client doesn't have a folder `node_modules` with all the dependencies.

Comment: I'm serving the file, so I tried as you suggested:
`<script type="module" src="./node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy.esm.js"></script>`
but I get this error:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`

@GG. @jabaa
Note that I am not using node.js, maybe it wasn't that clear in the question.

Comment: https://www.techiediaries.com/how-to-bring-node-js-modules-to-the-browser/

Comment: @JacobLockwood already tried to use browserify, very useful and works great, but it transpile your code and create a big js file. I just want to use ES6 modules... I cannot do that with browserify, can I?

Comment: https://mitchgavan.com/es6-modules/

Comment: @JacobLockwood  The issue here is that Mario is trying to use an npm package that actually has esm files in it, but can't get it to work as an ES6 module in the browser.  I don't think it's possible without rewriting chunks of the npm package (see my answer), but I'm happy to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't **think** this can work with ES6 modules in the browser because of the way that tippy.js references popper. It uses the syntax `import { createPopper, applyStyles } from '@popperjs/core';` which the browser can't understand.  There's an [issue about this on Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/31944) with regard to bootstrap, which has the same problem apparently.

I don't get the error you're getting by the way, I get the one in the issue.  My HTML file is as below with tippy.js installed in the same folder:

```
<body>
    <button id="myButton">My Button</button>
    <script type="module">
        import tippy from '../node_modules/tippy.js/dist/tippy.esm.js';
        tippy('#myButton', {
            content: 'Tooltip!',
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Running this gives error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@popperjs/core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

I don't think you can edit the import in tippy.js locally to fix this, either: popper's own imports then fail to work for me.

The workaround, as an [answer to the issue says](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/31944#issuecomment-743779745), is to use a module bundler like webpack if you want to create a .js file you can reference. This also begs the question of what the point is of an esm install if it can only be used from node.

Comment: I'm not getting that error because I change in the 'node_modules\tippy.js\dist\tippy.esm.js' file the syntax from `import { createPopper, applyStyles } from '@popperjs/core';` to `import { createPopper, applyStyles } from '../../@popperjs/core/dist/esm/popper.js';` **then** i get the `validation.ts:46 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` error

Comment: Ah, I think you've just moved the same problem down the stack.  It may be possible to patch popper.js to work, but changing third-party code isn't ideal.  What are you going to do when a new version arrives, for example?

Comment: You are right, it's not ideal. I'm learning and I was trying to make it work. So... did I choose the wrong package to make this generic question?
For package/projects like this should I be able to find an esm install that works with browsers?

Comment: I don't actually know the answer to that.  I do know it's still early days for ES6 modules in the browser.  A quick search shows that [jQuery probably works](https://fredriccliver.medium.com/using-npm-module-with-es6-import-in-browser-side-without-babel-roll-up-browserify-96a119292ea9), but I suspect many npm packages don't at present.